# Python3 wrapping functions

Tags: python, function, error-handling, wrapper

I couldn't find a solution to my questions anywhere so maybe I can get an answer to that here.
Basically I tried to printed a tuple with another function and then tried to wrap that output in another one. If I wrap the text in side the wrapped_string_linesplit() function it works perfectly, but I basically don't want it this way.
Maybe someone can explain where my mistakes are, and what would be a good solution to wrap it from another function. Thanks in advance

Working Solution:

```
def wrapped_string_linesplit(arg):
    print('#' * 30)
    for item in arg:
        print(item)
    print('#' * 30)


def welcome_message():
    first = 'Welcome to xyz'.center(30, ' ')
    second = ('#' * 30).center(30, ' ')
    third = 'New Game'.center(30, ' ')
    fourth = 'Load Game'.center(30, ' ')
    fifth = 'About'.center(30, ' ')
    sixth = 'Quit Game'.center(30, ' ')
    return first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth

wrapped_string_linesplit(welcome_message())
```

Output:

```
##############################
        Welcome to xyz        
##############################
           New Game           
          Load Game           
            About             
          Quit Game           
##############################
```

Then changing the code to the following, doesn't print the wrap at all without an error:

```
def message_wrapper(foo):
    def wrap():
        print('#' * 30)
        foo()
        print('#' * 30)
    return wrap
    

def string_linesplit(arg):
    for item in arg:
        print(item)

message_wrapper(string_linesplit(welcome_message()))
```

Output:

```
        Welcome to xyz
##############################
           New Game           
          Load Game           
            About             
          Quit Game           
##############################
```

The next one I don't understand at all, this one throws the Error

```
foo()
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
when calling foo() inside the message_wrapper().
Why does it have to have a return value to be callable from another function ?

```
def message_wrapper(foo):
    print('#' * 30)
    foo()
    print('#' * 30)


def string_linesplit(arg):
    for item in arg:
        print(item)

message_wrapper(string_linesplit(welcome_message()))
```

Comment: there is no method named `foo()` in your code. you declared `foo` as a variable in `message_wrapper` function. `foo` is a variable you can't call a variable

Comment: In last code snippet, `string_linesplit` doesn't return anything (None) hence, `foo` is none and it leads to error: `NoneType object is not callable`. I think you are complicating it a bit

Comment: ah thanks alot, things are clear now. Both answers lead to a possible solution. Not sure if still overcomplicating it tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused with given code snippet, but if I have to work around with given piece of code and give output as mentioned above:

```
def welcome_message():
    first = 'Welcome to xyz'.center(30, ' ')
    second = ('#' * 30).center(30, ' ')
    third = 'New Game'.center(30, ' ')
    fourth = 'Load Game'.center(30, ' ')
    fifth = 'About'.center(30, ' ')
    sixth = 'Quit Game'.center(30, ' ')
    return first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth


def string_linesplit(arg):
    for item in arg:
        print(item)

def message_wrapper(foo):
    print('#' * 30)
    string_linesplit(foo())
    print('#' * 30)

message_wrapper(welcome_message)
```

Output:

```
##############################
        Welcome to xyz        
##############################
           New Game           
          Load Game           
            About             
          Quit Game           
##############################
```